# Pressure drop in viscous flow

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, flow, viscosity

Can somebody explain why the pressure drop in the horizontal pipe (viscous flow) occurs itself? Is it due to head loss or it's just an assumption based on empirical evidence?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hagen%E2%80%93Poiseuille_equation#Derivation

Comment: It is due to viscous stresses resulting from velocity gradients, and, in particular due to the fact that the axial fluid velocity component at the wall is zero (no-slip boundary condition).

Answer (score 1):

The pressure drop in Poiseuille flow is required by conservation of momentum. The fluid's viscosity causes friction drag at the walls of the pipe, which would lead to a decrease in the flow velocity. Thus, if the flow velocity is to be kept constant, a pressure force needs to be exerted to counter the drag. This means the pressure at the inlet needs to be larger than that at the outlet in order to counter the drag.